# What is Materials Modeling?

Tags: terminology, materials-design

I'm a noob with zero knowledge of the subject. Materials Modeling is so specialized that it's not even on Wikipedia yet. Help orient a newcomer. What do you use it for? Can you use it to model materials for a bulletproof t-shirt, a superior mask to protect against COVID-19, a flux capacitor?

Comment: This reminds me of a beginner level question on Quantum Computing SE, which was actually ***very well*** received: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2381/2293

Comment: Are you using MM for Materials Modeling? I ask because, in general, it is used, in general, for Molecular Mechanics (that is a method to simulate molecules and materials).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is matter modeling?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4559/what-is-matter-modeling)

Answer (score 21):

I'm just as curious of a user here as you, but I was able to find that a [Materials Modeling Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_materials_science) does in fact exist. :)

> **Computational materials science and engineering** uses modeling,
>   simulation, theory, and informatics to understand materials. Main
>   goals include discovering new materials, determining material behavior
>   and mechanisms, explaining experiments, and exploring materials
>   theories. It is analogous to computational chemistry and computational
>   biology as an increasingly important subfield of materials science.

Comment: My mistake. I scrolled through a few search results, but didn't recognize it since the word order was different. Good to know, so I can write a better informed question next time :)

Answer (score 17):

Answering your last questions: yes, yes and yes.

One thing to consider is which approach do you want/need to use. You can use an atomistic approach where you simulate/model the properties and the material starting from the atomic structure of it (an input file with the list of atoms and its coordinates). The other approach is to use your material as a continuous medium and use its mechanical and optical experimental properties.

For the atomistic approach, take a look at this [post](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/17/what-are-the-main-computational-frameworks-used-in-materials-modeling).
How to simulate continuous materials, I recommend to take a look at the [COMSOL Multiphysics](https://www.comsol.com/) software (I'm in love with this, it is marvelous).